# Why is my session failing to work?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

My session does fails to resume when opening another file

I have 2 pages, `test.php` and `test2.php`. Each of my files are listed below.

test.php:

```
<?php
  session_save_path('sessBin');
  session_id('mySessionID');
  session_start();
  $_SESSION[1]="yo";
  echo $_SESSION[1];
?>
<a href="test2.php">go to test 2</a>
```

test2.php:

```
<?php
  session_save_path('sessBin');
  session_id('mySessionID');
  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION[1];
  echo "bleh";
?>
```

The first page returns:

`"yo" <a href="test2.php">go to test 2</a>`

however, when clicking on the link to go to test2.php, only this returns:

`"bleh"`

I did some research to find that cookies must be enabled. Well, they are... So what is wrong?

**NOTE: (A discovery from afterwards)**

I did notice that there were several files(including sess_mySessionID) in sessBin so the session is stored. However, the files are empty and the session does not seem to resume

Comment: test2, remove the 2 lines above `session_start();`

Comment: @Dagon alright I'll try... I don't think that will work, because, if I remember correctly, I originally coded it that way and it still didn't work. I'll change it and let you know...

Comment: @Dagon it didn't work...

Comment: What OS are you using; Unix, Windows? I'm guessing that changing your `session_save_path` is causing problems probably with file permissions or just a missing directory. Does the session work if you remove the top two lines of **both** files? (After the opening PHP tag)

Answer (score 0):

session_start needs to be defined at the top of every page, right after the opening php tag, on every page where the session data is expected to exist. You must do this before addressing any other session function or variable.

** Update to Answer Based On Your Comments **

check for white space before the opening php tag in test2.php. Also, enable error reporting. You might be sending something out before the session call that is causing session_start() to fail.

Comment: " right after the opening php tag" **no** and he already has anyway

Comment: Well, I checked. and I found no errrors. however, I did notice that there were several files(including `sess_mySessionID`) in `sessBin` so the session is stored. However, the files are empty and the session does not seem to resume

Answer (score 0):

test1.php

```
  // session_save_path('sessBin');
  // session_id('mySessionID');
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['test'] ="yo";
 echo $_SESSION['test'];

<a href="test2.php">go to test 2</a>
```

test2.php

```
    // session_save_path('sessBin');
    // session_id('mySessionID');
   session_start();
   echo $_SESSION['test'];
   echo "bleh";
```

Worked for me !

Comment: can you provide me a link that shows that this works?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

config.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```

In all your other files at the top add this:

```
include'config.php';
```

That way you will always have a file where you can put important stuff you might need on other pages as well, so you don't have to retype it every time.

Comment: I can't access `config.php`. My website is hosted on someone else's server who's php stuff I don't have access to

Comment: @AnOriginalAlias Oke, then just put session_start(); at the top of every page, that should also work.